# Owl Carousel overflow only right side

Tags: javascript, css, owl-carousel

So, I got this going on right now:

[image: Owl Carousel right now]

I want it to overflow the right side like this

[image]

But I can't get it working because I have a container to keep it centered, if I remove it the left side goes all the way to the left, margin and padding doesn't work because I don't know how much I need to align it with the other divs. I tried position absolute and z-index but when I drag the carousel the first element on the left disappears.

Any ideas?

Edit: It should have white space on the left just when it starts, when I drag some item I want the carousel to be full width.

Comment: put your code in fiddle.

Comment: I didn't know i could post only 1 link, I put it on wizzard's comment

Answer (score 0):

Just add a element right inside your container, within all the slide stuff. And add a total width to it (greater than the container). And add overflow: visible to the centered container.

Comment: It kinda works but not exactly, because after I drag the first item it goes missing, it should have white space on the left just when it starts, when I drag some item I want the carousel to be full width. Maybe I didn't explain what I needed, sorry my friend

Comment: I want it to behave like this http://codepen.io/lorrandavid/pen/rjrNrg but prevent the first element to go missing after it's scrolled of the screen

Comment: It's supposed to be like this [link](http://www.merci-michel.com/projects/)